# Why Fiddler shows diff port (50701) than the URL (50620)

Tags: fiddler

While my SPA app runs at http://localhost:**50620** (shows at Chrome), Fiddler shows it's captured at **50701**. I don't have a redirect inside of my app. Is it the browser link feature of the visual studio?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's spam from the `BrowserLink` feature of Visual Studio. You can use Fiddler rules to hide it. You can also look at the `Process` column in the Session list to see which process is responsible for a given session.